# Recurring payment with Paypal: what happens when I suspend and reactivate?

Tags: paypal

I have difficulties to find an answer on Paypal doc or on the web so here I come.

I am not sure of the behavior of suspending and then later reactivating a recurring payment on Paypal. Say I create a recurring payment profile that will credit $10w every month. We are September 1st and the next billing will happen October 1st. If I suspend the recurring profile on September 5th and I reactivate it on September 20th, will the next billing date change or will the user be still billed on October 1st?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They would still be billed on Oct. 1st.